# How do I use GetExtensibilityService when building a Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am working on a Visual Studio Extension. I am trying to get the ID of a code review request after it has been created/saved. I have added my own ITeamExplorerSection to the RequestCodeReview page. It makes sense to me that In my implementation of the SaveContext method of my section that I should be able to call the GetExtensibilityService on the page and retrieve the "CodeReviewId". I have several issues with this, the most important of which are: What object type am I trying to retrieve? and second is it available in the SaveContext Method. (or is this even the right approach)

Comment: According to description, I am sure where I could find related section about "CodeReviewId" on RequestCodeReview page and Code Reviews page. could you please describe it in detailed.

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea what you just asked. But I have discovered since posting the question, that the ID is available in the SaveContext method of my ITeamExplorerSection. So I have an answer to my second Issue. That leaves my question can I access it with the GetExtensibilityService Method and what object type should I pass in. It is viewable in the debugger teamExplorer.CurrentPage.Model.CRRequest.Id but It is not available because the classes are marked internal. Is reflection the only way this is available?